# Why does Tkinter bind() return error when using a class?

Tags: python, tkinter

#### Issue

Below, you can find a very short python program and the error output when it runs. `bind()` with a normal `tk.Frame` works fine, but when I try to make a class that inherits from `tk.Frame`, `bind()` breaks down.

#### Code

```
import tkinter as tk

def keyhandler(key):
    pass

class Test(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(master)
        self.bind("<Key>", keyhandler)


root = tk.Tk()
frame = Test(root)
```

#### Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Projects\pysnake\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    frame = Test(root)
  File "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Projects\pysnake\test.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.bind("<Key>", keyhandler)
  File "C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1392, in bind
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute '_w'
```

Comment: It should be `tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)` or `super().__init__(master)` not `tk.Frame.__init__(master)`

Comment: @TheLizzard ah alright thanks. Also, why do people comment instead of using the "Answer Your Question" button?

Comment: Because on stackoverflow, when I write an answer, I like to give a proper explanation. In this case, a comment was enough :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you aren't properly constructing your class. If you call the `__init__` method on a class you need to pass `self` as the first argument.

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
```

If you use `super`, you do not:

```
super().__init__(master)
```